# REACT REDUX - Updating record with the normalize data

Tags: reactjs, redux, normalizr

This is my initialState in reducer

```
const initialState = {
    ids:[],
    periodData: {}
}
```

this is my store after initial load
[image]

i want to update the remark for 
periodID: 3477dac1-d14a-4aef-b544-d8945b2442b9" from "test" to "test1"

this is my action to update:

```
export function updatePeriod(data){
    return function(dispatch){

        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("periodID", data.periodID);
        formData.append("periodName", data.periodName);
        formData.append("startDate", fecha.format(data.startDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
        formData.append("endDate", fecha.format(data.endDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
        formData.append("remark", data.remark);
        formData.append("isActive", 1);

        dispatch({type: PERIOD_FETCHING}); //Loading Indicator Appeared
        axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/api/setup/createPeriod`,formData,
        {
            headers:{authorization:`Bearer `+localStorage.getItem('laravel_user_token')}
        }
        ).then(response => {
            let result = {
                "periodID": data.periodID,
                "periodName": data.periodName,
                "startDate": fecha.format(data.startDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
                "endDate": fecha.format(data.endDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
                "remark": data.remark,
                "isActive": '1'
            }
            console.log(normalize(result, schema.periodSchema));
            dispatch({type: PERIOD_UPDATE,
                payload: normalize(result, schema.periodSchema)
            });
            dispatch({type: PERIOD_FETCHED}) //Loading Indicator Disappeared
        }).catch((e)=>{
            console.log(e)
             dispatch({type: PERIOD_FETCH_ERROR,
            });
        });
    }
}
```

This is the result of

> console.log(normalize(result, schema.periodSchema));

[image]

i still confuse about how my reducer going to update (PERIOD_UPDATE) the ids and periodData in my store.

Comment: Your reducer code is incomplete. It should be a function that  update the state with `schema.periodSchema` when the action `PERIOD_UPDATE` and